# How to change screen brightness in Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile using Compose

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to code up a way to set screen brightness to max after clicking a button in Kotlin Multiplatform Compose.

I have created an actual function that looks like this:

```kotlin
expect fun setBrightness(brightness: Float)
```

And then have implemented actual classes on both Android and iOS sides in commonMain module.

Android:

```kotlin
actual fun setBrightness(brightness: Float) {
    val window = requireActivity().window
    val layoutParams = window.attributes
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = brightness // set the brightness value between 0 and 1
    window.attributes = layoutParams
}
```

iOS:

```kotlin
actual fun setBrightness(brightness: Float) {
    UIScreen.main.brightness = brightness
}
```

The problem is that `requireActivity()` is unresolved in androidMain module in shared directory. How do I go around this? I guess this is because it is only available on the native Android side.

How do I set the brightness on both platforms using KMM so that is works in Compose?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider this approach:

1. Create an interface in the `commonMain`

```
   interface BrightnessController{
        fun setBrightness(value: Float)
    }
```

2. Then create `expect` class in the `commonMain`

```
    expect class BrightnessControllerImpl: BrightnessController
```

3. Then create `actual` class for Android

```
    actual class BrightnessControllerImpl(val context: Context): BrightnessController {
        ...
    }
```

4. Then you just need to inject the `context`(in **Koin** you can use `androidContext()`)

First, create expected variable for the module

```
    expect val brightnessModule: Module
```

Then create actual for all platforms (example for the **Android**)

```
    actual val brightnessModule = module {
        single<BrightnessController> { BrightnessControllerImpl(androidContext()) }
    }
```

Then to add the module in the `App` class (any name you have for class that extends `Application`)

```
    override fun onCreate(){
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@App)
            brightnessModule
        }
    }
```

**Note:**
You can also create separated modules without the `expect`/`actual`. For example call them `androidModule` and `iosModule`. Then you can add only the module you need into the platform.

Comment: How would you go exactly around injecting the context?

Comment: I've added the example in the answer @jasiu